# Assembly level programming to find the factorial

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

```
MVI B 07h
LXI H 0007h
LXI D 0007h
DCR B
LOOP1: DCR B
MOV C B
INR B
LOOP: DAD D
DCR C
JNZ LOOP
MOV E L
MOV D H
DCR B
JNZ LOOP1
HLT
```

I couldn't find out the problem in my code. Can you please help me out? It's giving me partially wrong answer. The two `LSB` bits are correct but not the `MSBs`.

Comment: Can you add little bit more info? For example what are you trying to do with these code, what is the expected answer and what went wrong from expected one?

Comment: Why not try writing it in plain C first, and then translate it to assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing the extra decrement (followed by the increment) at the `LOOP1` label to the `B` register but when `B` is one it causes `C` to become 0, which then wraps around to `FFh` and performs the multiply loop another 255 times.

Instead why don't you take out the `DCR B` / `INR B` and before the multiply loop just set the `H` register to 0. The full program would look like this:

```
MVI B, 07h
LXI H, 0007h
LXI D, 0007h
DCR B

LOOP1:
    MOV C, B
    LXI H, 0

    LOOP:
        DAD D
        DCR C
        JNZ LOOP

    MOV E, L
    MOV D, H
    DCR B
    JNZ LOOP1

HLT
```

Comment: It helps me a lot. Actually my approach for the loop is something different. As (H)(L) & (D)(E) register pair both contains the same value , for the first case let's say 7, 6 no of '7' s must be added. So we can run a loop for 5 times with the command 'DAD D', which will serve the purpose. But your approach is simpler, and also for mine it encounters a problem you have mentioned earlier.